# How to force all variables in Typescript to have a type declared

Tags: javascript, typescript

I understand that when you declare a variable in Typescript, you can choose whether or not to specify a type for the variable.  If no type is specified, the default "any" type is used.  Is there a way to force all variables to have a type declared, even if it may be "any".  As in, I want a compiler error when a type isn't specified.  This is so that programmers would be forced to give everything a type and prevent cases where variables are accidentally left as "any".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not true that a variable declared is necessarily without type in TypeScript. The TypeScript compiler will, when possible, infer a type based on the right hand side of a declaration.

For example:

```
var x = 150;
```

`x` will be a Number as the RHS is a number.

You can use the command line compile option to catch declarations where the type cannot be inferred by using `--noImplicitAny`:

> Warn on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.

This option would catch a case where a variable `d` for example is declared, yet not assigned to a value immediately.

```
var d;
```

Will produce an error:

> error TS7006: Parameter 'd' of 'test' implicitly has an 'any' type.

The compiler switch also catches parameters without a specified type, and as [@basarat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat) pointed out in a comment, it also catches return types and class/interface members.

There's a little more information in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/08/06/announcing-0-9-1.aspx) as well. Note that there's also an equivalent MSBuild/project setting available: `<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>`.

Comment: And return types, and class / interface members :)

Comment: @basarat - Yeah, totally forgot to include all of the places. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: The flag `--noImplicityAny` above should read `--noImplicitAny`.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is wrong. `var d;` does not produce an error with `--noImplicitAny`.

Comment: @phil294–this question and answer applied to a version that is 7 years old.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to disable gradual typing in TypeScript, because I want to try the language out on a new project. WiredPrairie's comment suggests that this answer might be outdated. What does `var d;` produce with `--noImplicitAny` in modern versions of TypeScript then?

Answer (score 12):

You could also set in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "noImplicitReturns": true,
     "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```